# Need to change url paramenter of share product pintrest

Tags: plugins, jquery, jquery-ui

Currently i want to change pintrest url. when i hit the pintrest url respective product image not open because not getting proper url

url as follows:

```
https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=https://test.testing.com/awesome/brand/abc-brand/&media=https://test.testing.com/awesome/brand/abc-brand/&description=ABC%20Brand
```

but if i hit below url then properly working image

```
https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=https://test.testing.com/newesome/brand/abc-brand/&media=https://test.testing.com/awesome/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/gints-gailis-l5zBtqUzYKM-unsplash.jpg
```

SO i want to change a icon url with specific product name.
Below is my pinterest icon html

```
<a class="jupiterx-social-share-link btn jupiterx-social-share-pinterest" href="https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=https://test.testing.com/newesome/brand/abc-brand/&amp;media=https://test.testing.com/awesome/brand/abc-brand/&amp;description=ABC%20Brand" target="_blank" aria-label="Share on Pinterest"><span class="jupiterx-icon jupiterx-icon-pinterest-p"></span></a>
```

Anyone have idea then let me know how to do this. I am thinking to do this using jquery but i cant understand how to start. ANyone have idea then let me know.
Please see attachmet with proper parameter in url nd other is not proper(image not display)

[image]

[image]